# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

About two days ago I did a pod update and got all the updates. After that, Xcode is throwing this error. I've gone through all Stackoverflow related items I could find, and mainly the issue was with Parse calls.

Now that I fixed all Parse calls, I am still seeing the problem, unfortunately. I removed all libraries and even created a new projects and copy paste all files into that project (without attaching any Pod to it) and that project also got the error... Something very odd.

This is the whole error:

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/MainController.swift
    cd /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/LoginController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/SplashController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/BabyNamesTableViewCell.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/ExampleOverlayView.swift -primary-file /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/MainController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/LikedController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/SearchPreferencesController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/CustomOverlayView.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/AppDelegate.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/SlideOutViewController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/BabyNames+CoreDataProperties.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/Constants.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/NotLikedController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/CustomKolodaView.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/SSASideMenu.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/Session.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/GetAvailableNames.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/BabyNames.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/InvitePartnerController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/PartnerSignUpController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/HttpUtils.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/MatchFoundController.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -I /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/BabyNames-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/BabyNames-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/BabyNames-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/BabyNames-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/BabyNames-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames -emit-module-doc-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name BabyNames -emit-module-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController.swiftdeps -o /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController.o

0  swift                    0x0000000109321fbb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43
1  swift                    0x00000001093226fb SignalHandler(int) + 379
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8e9fdeaa _sigtramp + 26
3  swift                    0x0000000107aa4e58 swift::NominalTypeDecl::prepareExtensions() + 40
4  swift                    0x00000001075e8707 swift::SILWitnessVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::SILGenConformance>::visitProtocolDecl(swift::ProtocolDecl*) + 999
5  swift                    0x00000001075e5ee5 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::getWitnessTable(swift::ProtocolConformance*) + 277
6  swift                    0x00000001076355b0 (anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::emitType() + 1264
7  swift                    0x000000010763504e swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*) + 30
8  swift                    0x00000001075bdbdb swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 779
9  swift                    0x00000001075be790 swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit*, llvm::Optional<unsigned int>, bool, bool) + 928
10 swift                    0x00000001075beb3d swift::performSILGeneration(swift::FileUnit&, swift::SILOptions&, llvm::Optional<unsigned int>, bool) + 109
11 swift                    0x0000000107412992 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 11442
12 swift                    0x000000010740fad3 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2691
13 swift                    0x000000010740c154 main + 2324
14 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff9215b5ad start + 1
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/LoginController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/SplashController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/BabyNamesTableViewCell.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/ExampleOverlayView.swift -primary-file /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/MainController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/LikedController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/SearchPreferencesController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/CustomOverlayView.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/AppDelegate.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/SlideOutViewController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/BabyNames+CoreDataProperties.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/Constants.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/NotLikedController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/CustomKolodaView.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/SSASideMenu.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/Session.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/GetAvailableNames.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/BabyNames.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/InvitePartnerController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/PartnerSignUpController.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/HttpUtils.swift /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/MatchFoundController.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -I /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames/BabyNames/BabyNames-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/BabyNames-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/BabyNames-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/BabyNames-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/BabyNames-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/fcaldas/projects/iOS/BabyNames -emit-module-doc-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name BabyNames -emit-module-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController.swiftdeps -o /Users/fcaldas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BabyNames-fkrzmfswhriloueylaikeccbmbxd/Build/Intermediates/BabyNames.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BabyNames.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainController.o
```

Here's a PasteBin of the issue: http://pastebin.com/Ff02JYBp

Can anyone help?

Comment: very difficult to debug by just looking at that error. Is your project available on github or something? I could have a play around with it

Comment: @Scriptable I will upload it and send you the link in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed in their github issues: https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda/issues/79